# Previous value and current value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to pivot the following data such that I can have a previous column and a current column based on the values in column rn.  If there is only 1 record  then the current and the previous values will be the same value.
(I am using ssms 2008)

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST1
(ACCT_ID INT, RN INT, LoadDate Date)

INSERT INtO #TEST1 VALUES (1, 1, '2016-12-21')
INSERT INtO #TEST1 VALUES (2, 1, NULL)
INSERT INtO #TEST1 VALUES (3, 1, '2017-10-06')
INSERT INtO #TEST1 VALUES (3, 2, NULL)
INSERT INtO #TEST1 VALUES (4, 1, '2016-12-21')

SELECT * FROM #TEST1
ACCT_ID RN  LoadDate
1   1   2016-12-21
2   1   NULL
3   1   2017-10-06
3   2   NULL
4   1   2016-12-21
```

Based on the data above, I did a pivot table

```
SELECT ACCT_ID, [1] as Prev, [2] as Curr FROM 
(
    SELECT * fROM #TEST1 S
    pivot(  MAX(LoadDate) for RN IN ([1],[2]) ) U 
)X
```

How can for example acct_id 1 and 4 have the same value in current as the previous value.

Comment: Show the results that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if pivot will work in this case, I apologize if you specifically require an answer using pivot.

Here I'm taking the MAX(RN) via subquery, then doing select statements for the previous and current LoadDate. The current date is the date provided by the MAX(RN). The previous date is the date of MAX(RN) - 1 if MAX(RN) is greater than 1, else it is the previous date where RN equals 1.

```
SELECT dT.ACCT_ID
      ,(SELECT T1.LoadDate FROM #TEST1 T1 WHERE T1.ACCT_ID = dT.ACCT_ID AND T1.RN = CASE WHEN dT.MaxRN = 1 THEN 1 ELSE dT.MaxRN - 1 END) [Prev]
      ,(SELECT T1.LoadDate FROM #TEST1 T1 WHERE T1.ACCT_ID = dT.ACCT_ID AND T1.RN = dT.MaxRN) [Curr]
  FROM (
         SELECT ACCT_ID
               ,MAX(RN) [MaxRN]
           FROM #TEST1
          GROUP BY ACCT_ID
 ) AS dT
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need something like this. It displays the `Curr` value if the `Prev` is empty.

```
 select acct_id, curr, case when prev = ' ' then null else coalesce(prev, curr) end
 from
 (
    SELECT acct_id,
      max(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN loaddate END) as Curr,
      max(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN coalesce(loaddate, ' ') END) as Prev
    FROM #test1 t
    GROUP BY acct_id
 ) t
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=254a940c51fdd04425bdab8097cd6f5f)

Comment: That worked but it affected ID 3.  That record had 2 rows of data.  The 1st one had a value and the 2nd did not have and I wanted it to remain like that...

Comment: @user3059409 yes it has `null` value which is replaced ... i will think about it

Comment: @user3059409 try it now

Answer (score 0):

I would use conditional aggregation:

```
select acct_id,
       max(case when rn = 1 then loaddate end) as load_date,
       max(case when rn = 2 then loaddate end) as load_date_prev
from #test1 t
group by acct_id;
```

Comment: That did not work.  ID 1 and 4 have null  values in the load_date_prev instead of having the same value as load_date